# Delete json object from jsonb type column based on key of json object in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

can anybody tell me query  to remove entire json object from array in jsonb type column by given id stored in json object.

example : I have data column in t1 table. Type of data column is jsonb.
Record in data column is as follows

```
"type" : "users",
"info" : [
{
"id":1,
"name" : "user1"
},
{
"id":2,
"name" : "user2"
}
]
}
```

Now I want to delete entire json object which has id = 1 ( I want to identify the object by json object id)

The expected result is

```
{
"type" : "users",
"info" : [
{
"id":2,
"name" : "user2"
}
]
}
```

Please help me out with queries.
Thanks in advance

Comment: which postgresql version you are actually using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a subquery for each row on [`jsonb_array_elements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) that are then [aggregated back to an array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html):

```
UPDATE t1
SET data = jsonb_set(data, '{info}', (
  SELECT COALESCE(jsonb_agg(element), '[]'::jsonb)
  FROM jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'info') element
  WHERE element ->> 'id' <> '1'
))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Bergi. It worked for me :D . Though if there is only one json object in 'info' array.. It throws error with "Null value not allowed".. though I'm handling this in "try - except" statement in python.. Is there any way to handle this scenario in query itself?
Although.. Thankyou so much.. for helping me out with this query :)

Comment: Ah, `jsonb_agg` returns `NULL` when there are no columns

Answer (score -1):

##Here is a simple query to solve above problem ##

> update t1 set data = jsonb_set(data,'{info}',jsonb_path_query_array(data,'$.info[*]?(@."id" != 1)'));